# Statements about normal operator

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{L}(H), H$ - Hilbert space.
Let call $A$ - normal, if $A^{\perp}A = AA^{\perp}.$
I should prove this statements:
1) $A$ - normal $\Leftrightarrow ||Ax|| = ||A^{\perp}x||$
2) $A$ - normal $\Rightarrow ||A^n|| = ||A||^n$
3) $A$ - normal $\Rightarrow ||A|| = \sup_{||x||=1} |(Ax,x)|$
4) $A$ - normal, $[A, B] = 0 \Rightarrow [A^{\perp}, B] = 0$
5) $A$ - normal, $A^2 = A \Rightarrow A = A^{\perp}$
I know, how prove first and third statements. First we can solve by definition. Third I can prove from Cauchy-Bunyakowski theorem.
But how can I solve other items?